# Ember route understanding

Tags: ember.js, routes

I tried to understand Ember's getting started app (Todo app); my local copy of app does not work, same as the online preview:
http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/
(at the end of the page)

if you add at least two todos, then you delete one of them and click on the "Active" link, everything seems ok, but if you click on the "All" link then the deleted todo is still there; and you can't delete or update it...

in my local copy of the app, i can see that clicking on the "All" link, i am redirected to "index.html#/"; this is the cause because if i type the "index.html" URL, without the "#", everything is ok and the deleted todos are not showed. Everything goes right also if i press F5 on the "index.html#/" URL.

How can i make it work without pressing F5 to update the page?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i figured out that this was due to an incompatibility between ember rc3 and ember-data e324f0e;
The issue has been resolved and now the app is working fine with ember rc 5 and ember-data-latest